# Is there a way to selectively use mouse events on overlayed elements?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material, dom-events

I have a slider component that should handle all click events. I have overlaid a few tool-tip icons over this slider using absolute positioning. I want to be able to mouseover the tool-tip icons and trigger their mouseover event, but I don't want these icons to block clicking on the slider.

Any ideas?

For the slider, I'm using Angular Materials' "mat-slider". For the icons, I have mat-icons that are using matTooltip.

I don't think this question is really Angular specific necessarily, but I'd greatly appreciate any help :)

Not much code to show, but here's an image of what the slider looks like. The comment icons can block clicking on the slider. Right now, I have the comment icons use this class:

```
.comment-icon {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a tough one since something like `pointer-events: none;` would prevent hover and even JS from listening to mouseover events.

What you could do is add a click listener to the tooltips, and if the mouse position is within the bounds of the slider it'll trigger the click event on that too.

Something like:

```
document.querySelector('.comment-icon').addEventListener('click', e => {
    const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
    const sliderBounds = slider.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (e.clientX >= sliderBounds.left && e.clientX <= sliderBounds.right
    && e.clientY >= sliderBounds.top && e.clientY <= sliderBounds.bottom) {
        slider.click();
  }
});
```

Here's a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfpv5oka/2/

Comment: Thanks Dan, I like your idea. I think what I'm gonna try is to bypass this problem by making the click event on the little comment-icon emit the same event as what clicking on the slider would do. 

What's a bit complicated for me is that the slider is a 'mat-slider' Angular Material component so I can't really change its insides too much.